# Creating a web project in netbeans without selecting a server

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, war, netbeans6.5

I'd like to create a web project in NetBeans, but I don't want it to deploy anything to the server autmatically. I just want to be able to create a war file, which I will upload to the server manually. From what I know the tomcat installation there will autmatically pickup new war archives. Is it possible to start a new web project without defining a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm.

You can create a Maven based Web Application project... that doesn't require that you select a server when you create the project.

You can create an Ant based project, too.  You just avoid using the Run/Deploy/Debug/Profile menu items and the project will not be deployed, so it will not be autodeployed as you make changes....  Autodeployment is triggered once the project is deployed in an IDE usage 'session'.